# Ruby Shoes App, Gem Chef: bad response Not Found 404

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a Shoes app that will call Chef classes and modules. To accomplish this, I'm using Shoes 3.2.21-gtk2 and using the following code before my Shoes app code:

```
Shoes.setup do
  gem 'chef'
end

Shoes.app do
  ...
end
```

When I run the app from Shoes, it attempts to install chef, and even determines the latest version (12.0.3) however, I get the following error during the installation:

```
bad response Not Found 404 (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.10.1-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz)
```

This version of Shoes is using Ruby 2.1.5-p273, which satisfies the minimum requirement of the Chef gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/chef

Is there some bug in Shoes with its ssl code? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too.

The error occurs when trying to install the "[pry gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pry)". In my case was a bug that happened in my old version of rubygems (2.4.6).

***FIX:***

**1 - Install another version of rubygems**

gem update --system 2.4.4

**2 - Install pry**

gem install pry

The error also happens with the 2.4.5 version of rubygems: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1120